# ASA cannot get traffic to pass port forward

Tags: cisco-asa, acl, port-forwarding

I'm not able to get port forwarding to work for some reason on my asa 5555-x.

I have tried the below config:

```
!
object network SERVER
 host 192.168.1.20
!
object service SERVICE_TCP_9982
 service tcp source eq 9982
!
nat (lan,wan) source static SERVER interface service SERVICE_TCP_9982 SERVICE_TCP_9982
access-list ALLOW_SERVER line 1 extended permit tcp any object SERVER eq 9982
```

This does not work for some reason and when checking with `capture DROP type asp-drop all buffer 500000 match tcp host any host 192.168.1.20 eq 9982` I get a list of the following:

```
external_ip.13101 > wan_ip.9982: S 4229306080:4229306080(0) win 62727 <mss 1318,sackOK,timestamp 967884582 0,nop,wscale 7> Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: My interfaces are configured as follows:

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif wan
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif lan
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
object network lan-subnet
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
!
object network lan-subnet
 nat (lan,wan) dynamic interface
!
route wan 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.1.1.2 1
!
```

The goal is to allow connections from behind the wan interface port tcp 9982 to internal lan ip 192.168.1.20 tcp port 9982, so basic port forwarding configuration.

This is all configuration done after factory reset

Comment: What are you trying to do? Allow a connection outbound from the SERVER with TCP source port 9982 or do you want to allow an inbound connection from any to the SERVER with source port 9982?

Comment: I recommend you share some info on your desired result and more of the configuration. We need to be able to see how the interfaces are configured (lan and wan are not the common interface names on ASA) and how the access list(s) are applied to them to make a good suggestion.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer Updated the question with the interface configurations. No other configuration is applied. I want to allow connections from wan to the lan host 192.168.1.20. I'm trying to follow this tutorial article https://deltaconfig.com/cisco-asa-port-forwarding-static-nat/

Comment: I think you want destination port, not source

Comment: @RonTrunk Tried to change that to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the acl:s not being configured properly. Also the nat statement was really bloated. I got the following configuration to work with passing traffic through from two different ports from wan to server 192.168.1.20:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif wan
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif lan
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
route wan 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.1.1.2 1 !Default route
!
object network SERVER
 host 192.168.1.20
!
object network NAT1
 nat (lan,wan) static interface service tcp 9982 9982
object network NAT2
 nat (lan,wan) static interface service tcp 9983 9983
!
access-list ALLOW_SERVER extended permit tcp any object SERVER eq 9982
access-list ALLOW_SERVER extended permit tcp any object SERVER eq 9983
!We have to apply the acl to wan interface
access-group ALLOW_SERVER in interface wan
```

I could not figure a clean way of adding multiple successive ports to the nat rule (like port range 80-88 etc.), please do point out if that is possible and also point out any beginner mistakes that I might have made here that are not immediately obvious.

Comment: Using objects you can define a port range as mentioned here:
https://www.networkstraining.com/cisco-asa-firewall-commands-cheat-sheet/